# How to remove SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, slider

I am using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) in my iPhone app.

After successful login I am creating SWRevealViewController from my viewcontroller.

```
        profileView *frontViewController = [[profileView alloc] init];
        RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

        UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
        UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

        SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
        revealController.delegate = self;



       frontViewController.user_id = [defaults objectForKey:@"userid"];
        appDelegate.user_id = [defaults objectForKey:@"userid"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:revealController animated:YES];
```

Now I want to logout and come back to viewcontroller. I tried poptoRootviewcontroller, but not working. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Call from your front/rear viewController:

```
[self.revealViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your action:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
        UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];

        [reveal pushFrontViewController:nvc animated:YES];
```